# How to get Pandora to be a music service on Alexa app

Tags: alexa

How do I get Pandora as a choice of music services on my Alexa app?

Answer (score 2):

[Pandora.com](https://help.pandora.com/s/article/Pandora-and-Amazon-Echo-Alexa?language=en_US) has some pretty straightforward steps:

- Start the Alexa app
- Select `Settings` from the menu
- Go to `Music` then `Pandora`
- Select Enable
- Enter your account information for the Pandora service

Your music should now show up in the Alexa app.  Hope it helps!